# MYSQL INSERT not adding values to table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am using the INSERT function to try and add new values to a table. While there is no error when I run the query, it is not showing the new attributes added to the table. I have no idea why. I also have safe updates turned off. The values entered also match the value type for each column of the table.

CODE ENTERED:

```
INSERT INTO productlines
VALUES 
('Jet Packs', 'Futuristic flying machines that only exist in prototype.', NULL, NULL),
('Jet Skis', 'Much more realistic things that very much exist already.', NULL, NULL),
('Wheelbarrows', 'I cannot believe we actually stock these.', NULL, NULL);

SELECT *
FROM productlines;


CREATE TABLE `productlines` (
  `productLine` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `textDescription` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `htmlDescription` mediumtext,
  `image` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productLine`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: please add your create table for productlines

Comment: Did you try clicking the Refresh button.

Comment: Clicking the refresh button did not do anything for me @Barmar.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the utility you're using. The query looks OK.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @nbk

Comment: we need the structure of your table, also if there a triggers

Comment: We need more info as nbk requested, as you can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckFJW54YHXhZah18g67HeY/1 problem is not in code you presented...

Comment: i believe i have added the table structure in another image @nbk

Comment: @scottmorris did you try the solution i added below?

Comment: images are bad see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: thanks i think i have properly formatted it now @nbk

Comment: there is no problem that i can see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=573fa0981a684e7ce39e5b7586534e66

Comment: yes unfortunately I have no idea why it's not showing up for me. @nbk

Comment: check error log from mysql and if nothing os to be seen, enable general log to see what happens in your database

Comment: Maybe your session has expired. With a lousy MySQL admin tool this could happen that your query is sent with ajax to the backend and if your session has expired they just ignore it failing to remind you to login again.

Comment: @nbk The error log when I run gives no error just Query completed. I'm not quite sure how to enable the general log I looked it up but still a bit confusing.

Comment: So do I need to restart my instance or quit mySQL? @MajidFouladpour

Comment: Well it only could happen if you are using a web based admin. If so, just reload the tab to see if you are still logged in or not.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour I don't think I am. I have MySQL downloaded on my laptop and am using a local instance.

Comment: I figured it out! It turns out I needed to run the INSERT statement on its own first and then it started showing up once I ran the SELECT query.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on , do you have autocommit set to off ? (SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit';)

Comment: then you have the auto_commit disabled.

Comment: I ran SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='autocommit'; and it says autocommit is on. I'm on MySQL Workbench Version 8.0.21

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO 
    [name of your **TABLE**](col1, col2, col3)#NAME OF YOUR COLUMNS
VALUES
    ('value for col1','value for col2','value for col3'),
```

**You didn't add the column names for which you are performing the insert**

Comment: I added the column names in this format and this made no change

Comment: can you paste here what you wrote

Comment: '''
INSERT INTO productlines(productLine,textDescription,htmlDescription,image)

VALUES 
('Jet Packs', 'Futuristic flying machines that only exist in prototype.', NULL, NULL),  
('Jet Skis', 'Much more realistic things that very much exist already.', NULL, NULL),
 ('Wheelbarrows', 'I cannot believe we actually stock these.', NULL, NULL);


SELECT *
FROM productlines;
'''